# Problema al mandar mail con PHP

Tags: php, pdo, email

Estoy intentando mandar un `mail` justo después de insertar registros en la base de datos.

Pero parece que tiene algun conflicto el PDO con la sentencia mail(), ya que el PDO funciona perfecto (sin hacer el envio del correo)

Pero al ingresar la linea de codigo para enviar el mail, no se ejecuta nada de codigo..

solo me muestra Error de Pagina:

> Esta página no funciona plataforma.mx no puede procesar esta solicitud
>   en este momento. HTTP ERROR 500

Este es mi código:

```
if ($departamento === "True") { 

        try { 
        /* Creamos La Conexión con PDO, modificar los valores respectivos*/
        $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',"xxx", "xxx",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        /* Creamos la Transacción*/
        $bd->beginTransaction();
        /* Preparamos la Sentencia*/
        $sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO temporal8 (articulo,fraccion,inciso,nombre,documento,ano,departamento,rango_actualizacion,fecha_actualizacion,consecutivo,mes,ruta) VALUES (:articulo,:fraccion,:inciso,:nombre,:documento,:ano,:departamento,:rango_actualizacion,:fecha_actualizacion,:consecutivo,:mes,:ruta)")or die("fallo al insertar datos: ".mysqli_error($link));
        /* Le pasamos el valor fijo antes de entrar al For */
        $sentencia->bindValue(':articulo', $articulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':fraccion', $fraccion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':inciso', $inciso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':documento', $nombreDoc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':ano', $ano, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':rango_actualizacion', $rango, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':fecha_actualizacion', $nuevafecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':consecutivo', $consecutivo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':mes', $mes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sentencia->bindValue(':ruta', $destino, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $array = array("ALUMBRADO", "CATASTRO","COMPRAS");
        $count = count($array);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

            $sentencia->bindValue(':departamento', $array[$i] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sentencia->execute();

        }        

         /* Aplicamos los Cambios en La BD */
        $bd->commit();
        header('Location: http://plataforma.mx');
        mail("$email1,$email2", "nuevo correo", "mensaje","FROM: soporte@elhuerto.mx");    

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
             /* Cancelamos La Transacción por si exista Error*/
            $mbd->rollBack();
            echo "Se Presento Un Error :  " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar!

Comment: Por qué la re dirección `header('Location: http://plataforma.mx');` ? si realiza esto la linea de `email` se ejecuta?  una opción mejorada para enviar email sería emplear [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: @Dev.Joel.. La re direccion la utilizo para, al momento de insertar los registros me redirija a la pagina principal..pero no encuentro la forma de que tambien, despues de insertar los registros, me envie el correo..

Comment: Entiendo , pero al redireccionar no se ejecutará la ultima linea de `email`. quizá debería enviar el `email` y luego re direccionar.. además mencione en el primer comentario lo que puede emplear. `PHPMailer` es mejor opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pone la redireccion después del envío del mail y deberías usar el PHPMailer para enviar correo.

```
mail("$email1,$email2", "nuevo correo", "mensaje","FROM: soporte@elhuerto.mx");    
header('Location: http://plataforma.mx');
```